# Element 'script' is missing required attribute 'type'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am NEW in JS. All I have is a ASP.NET Web Page and I included a JS in my page of showing tweets. Here is the JS code:

```
 <div id="tweet">
        <font class="title">Recent Tweets</font>
        <br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert($ && $.fn ? $.fn.jquery : "jQuery not defined")
              $(function () {
                    $("#favorites").tweet({
                        avatar_size: 32,
                        count: 3,
                        username: "atpworldtour",
                        favorites: true,
                        loading_text: "loading list..."
                    });
                });

       </script>

    </div>
```

Now under it is showing me: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

What am I doing stupid wrong here?

---

**Update**: Now I am getting this error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: You could add `type=text/javascript` to the script tag but I think it's now optional.

Comment: @ide: probably need the appropriate doctype to avoid the warning then

Comment: I am getting this err: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: @klm9971 have you included jQuery on the page?

Comment: @klm9971 : the error that you posted is too generic to provide a solution.
Also as @Box9 asked, have you included jQuery ? And do you get the same error in Firefox and IE ?

Comment: Do you have `jQuery` included in the page? Try adding this line as the first line of your javascript: `alert($ && $.fn ? $.fn.jquery : "jQuery not defined")`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            alert($ && $.fn ? $.fn.jquery : "jQuery not defined")
                  $(function () {
                        $("#favorites").tweet({
                            avatar_size: 32,
                            count: 3,
                            username: "atpworldtour",
                            favorites: true,
                            loading_text: "loading list..."
                        });
                    });

           </script>

Comment: @klm9971: yes, what is "alert"ed by the above script?

Comment: also make sure none of your scripts are using `type="application/javascript"` in IE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check all your JS includes and make sure that none of them are using `type="application/javascript"`. All of them should be using `type="text/javascript"`. This is only true if your code fails only in IE.

I had this issue once and it drove me nuts trying to figure it out

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps add the `type` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

This is required in HTML4 and XHTML, but not in HTML5 (see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/element/script)).

Answer (score -1):

In   $("#favorites") ,'favorites' is a id of an element on the DOM where probably your tweets will load, do you have element having id 'favorites'?

Comment: This doesn't appear to relate to the problem he's experiencing.

Comment: Yea, I am keep getting err: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected